# zsh has problem with star wildcard in long path with space in name on Mac?

Tags: osx, zsh, ls

If I run a simple command containing the star wildcard, for example:

```
$ ls -ltr *.txt
```

in a folder with a long path and a space (it does contains `*.txt` files):

```
/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/XXX/Projects/YYYYYYYYYYYY/paper/zzzzzz_wwwwwwwww
```

I get the following error message:

```
zsh: no matches found: *.txt
```

FYI my OS is:

```
System Version: macOS 10.13.5 (17F77)
Kernel Version: Darwin 17.6.0
```

Comment: Can you show the files in your folder `/Volume/XXX/My Folder/` ?

Comment: You simply do not have any files matching that pattern in that folder.

Comment: I have just edited the question to state explicitly that txt files are present in that folder

Comment: Actually I check that the command works on other folders with space. Maybe the problem is due to the path length?

Comment: @IgorFobia No, you have not shown that the folder contains .txt files. The name of the folder does not matter at all, nor the path length.

Comment: Strange bugs in a Google Drive mount would not surprise me. Is the problem reproducible in a purely local filesystem?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley good observation. So far I was not able to reproduce the error outside the folder where I mount the Google Drive

Comment: @Kusalananda I said that the folder contains *txt files. I can also open them from the terminal

Comment: What about `echo *.txt`? What about `sh -c 'ls -ltr *.txt'`?

Comment: @Gilles `echo *.txt` outputs a space-separated line with all the names of the `txt` files. `sh -c 'ls -ltr *.txt'` instead gives the usual error `ls: *.txt: No such file or directory`

Comment: That's strange. What about these other commands? `a=(*.txt); echo number of files: $#a; echo total length: ${#${(j: :)a}}; getconf ARG_MAX` and also `=echo *.txt` (with the initial `=`)

Comment: @Gilles The first sequence gives me this output, with the correct number of files 
`number of files: 2
total length: 23
262144`

If I use the same sequence with `a=(echo *.txt)` I got a wrong number of files:
`number of files: 3
total length: 28`
The final number is the same. The filenames are `empty.txt` and `something.txt` for a total of 22 characters.

Comment: @IgorFobia `a=(echo *.txt)` sets `a` to an array whose first element is `echo`, so `a=(echo *.txt)` is consistent with `a=(*.txt)`. The interesting take here is that it is not due to the length of the command line. And what about `=echo *.txt`? What about `wc *.txt`? The goal of these is to see whether this is specific to `ls` or happens to other commands.

Comment: @Gilles The command `=echo *.txt` gives the same correct output given by `echo *.txt`. The command `wc *.txt` gives a correct output
`       0       0       0 empty.txt
       1       1       5 something.txt
       2       4      23 two_lines.txt
       1       2      13 two_words.txt
       4       7      41 total`.
So it looks like it is an `ls` problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Maybe related to [this bug observed with `ls` in fish](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/3680)? And possibly [a similar issue observed in zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/4161#issuecomment-153442082).